# What's the best way to connect an Android App to MySQL?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I would like to write an Android App (with Android Studio) which uses a MySQL database.

What's the best way to implement it?

I have found on internet that I should write php files which send queries to the database. Then the php page return a JSON object which should be processed by the Android App (or something like that...). 
Is this solution safe? Because I have to handle sensitive data like emails or GPS position.

Or else, are there other safe ways to let Android App connect to and retrieve information from the database?

Comment: there are ton of ways you could do such thing. but it really depends on how you want to implement your system. there is nothing wrong php and mysql. what you really should do is sends your data over secure connection ssl and manipulate them with secure way. that is all what i know

Comment: If you want to use api calls with Json you need a security token for authorization.

Comment: The "best" way involves security protocols and proper error handling. There is nothing wrong with PHP + MySQL, though it is not secure by default. You could just as easily do the same backend in NodeJS + Mongo, for example. Point being - your backend is not tied to your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a web service which connects to your server, and a back-end program written in nodejs or PHP or Java or Python or any other programming language which has support (connectors/libraries) for MySQL database.